# How can I have one page subscribe to messages from multiple different pages using Xamarin MessagingCenter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the situation that I have.  On DeckPage, I subscribe to a message like this:

```
public void OnAppearing()
{
    RefreshLables();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CardFormatPageViewModel>(
       this,
       "RefreshDeckConfigsLabels",
       sender => { RefreshLables(); });
    }

    private void RefreshLables()
    {
        -- refresh code
    }

public void OnDisappearing()
{
    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<CardFormatPageViewModel>(this,"RefreshDeckConfigsLabels");
}
```

This works good and I am sending a message from the CardFormatPageViewModel like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "RefreshDeckConfigsLabels");
```

I also want to be able to send messages to DeckPage from OptionPageViewModel:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "RefreshDeckConfigsLabels");
```

Plus from more models.

Is there a way I can code the subscribe so I can subscribe to one common message that will be accepted if it comes from CardFormatPageViewModel, OptionPageViewModel or the other View Models that need to make it refresh or do I have to do a subscription for every one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "RefreshDeckConfigsLabels");
```

and

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(
   this,
   "RefreshDeckConfigsLabels",
   sender => { RefreshLables(); });
```

Comment: Okay that looks like a very good solution.  I was not aware it was possible to use <object> there.  I will try that out and update the question later.  Thank you.